# How to query user accounts with domain '@gmail.com' using Identity query tool in SAP CDC or GIGYA

Tags: sql, mysql, regex, gigya

I'm unable to query or filter user accounts with email domains that end with `@gmail.com` in the SAP CDC Identity query tool since it does not support the SQL `LIKE` operator as normally use for querying in MySQL or Postgres SQL. The only option here seems to be using REGEX but I'm unable to query it as my syntax is wrong and not sure what the correct syntax is as it is not clearly shown in the documentation how to use REGEX operator. Does anyone know what is wrong here with my syntax or know any other alternative that satisfies these criteria?

I tried using the REGEX operator but got an incorrect syntax error near `WHERE`. Example:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
WHERE profile.emailIDs 
REGEX ('@gmail.com$')
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: REGEX is actually `LIKE`. And it is not a full-power REGEX. For example, it does not support `$` as far as I remember.

Comment: It sounds like `url_encode()` was called an extra time by the _sender_.

Answer (score 0):

You can not search partial string on encrypted fields. You can only use exact match. Email addresses are an encrypted field. There is no way to search for all emails of a particular domain.

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/b32ce0918af44c3ebd7e96650fa6cc1d.html

[image]

Additionally, profile.emailIDs is not a standard property name. You are looking for loginIDs, profile.email, or emails.

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/413100f670b21014bbc5a10ce4041860.html